# Assign MultipleLines in a cell in MSEXCEL using C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

I am exporting datatable in MSEXCEL.I need to Assign MultipleLines in a cell in MSEXCEL using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the content with a line break but not a carriage return+line break. A line break is typically represented as `\n`.